# How can i increase text length limit of Document title using PHP Script (Vtlib Function) from my CRM vtiger 7

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

How can i increase text length limit of Document title using PHP Script (Vt-lib Function) from my vtiger7

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for Updating field Length through vtlib API functions or any other function from CRM. You have to do it directly from the database using ALTER query.

Still, if you want to **update other vtiger_field table values**, do it through CRM functions, you can get an Object of the field using the below code line and then set the new value and call the update function.

```
$fieldId = getFieldid(getTabid('ModuleName'), 'fieldName');
$fieldModel = Vtiger_Field_Model::getInstance($fieldId);
if ($fieldModel) {
    $fieldModel->set('presence', 1);
    $fieldModel->__update();
}
```